# Can a graph have multiple identical elements?

Tags: graphs

Can a graph have multiple nodes that have the same value ? For instance, could a graph holding numbers have the same number present multiple times across the itself ?

My current approach is to not allow the insertion of the same element multiple times, and to instead enable an element to have an associated value, is it correct ?

Thank you.

Comment: Graphs don't have values at all, per se. Whatever you add is your call. What semantics do your elements have?

Answer (score 4):

Graphs don't have values.  Graphs don't hold numbers.  You don't insert a value into a graph.  Graphs have vertices and edges.

You can augment a graph to associate each vertex (node) with a number, if you wish.  If you do that, it's up to you to define whether or not you allow two different vertices to have the same number or not.  There is no universal answer.

Comment: How are you accessing a specific node in the graph then ? Let's say you want to call a function such as "lowestCostFrom(node, to:node) how would you retrieve the appropriate node ? Even internally, what is the way you differentiate nodes ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise A graph is a set of vertices and a set of edges. How you implement that in a computer program is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on D.W.'s answer, it seems to me that you're confusing a graph (the mathematical) object and an implementation of a graph in some programming language on some computer.

Mathematically, a graph consists of two sets $V$, and $E \subseteq V\times V$. There is nothing special about these sets, so vertices don't contain numbers, they don't have a "way to differentiate them", they're just elements of a set, and hence by definition, different. (As an aside, unless you're working with a rather unhelpful set theory, you will have at least some notion of equality, so you can use that to tell if two objects are the same.)

When implement a graph as a data structure, then the answers to all your questions are "it depends on how you want to do it". You can label things, you can not label things, vertices can also be containers, edges can also be containers, they can all be objects if you're using an OO language, or you can just have a bunch of arrays that store all the information however you want and you write code to piece it all together. There's no single right way to do it, you have to work out what makes sense in the situation you're in.

Comment: Thank you, so, mathematically, those certifies should have coordinates, right ?

Comment: What coordinates?